# how to sort data on a comma separated list in ssrs report

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a comma separated list on a cell that I made with COALESCE keyword like below:

```
SELECT 
    @RelatorFirmDeals = COALESCE(@RelatorFirmDeals + ', ', '') + ISNULL(H.dtm_unittypename, '') + '-' + ISNULL(CAST(H.dtm_unitno as nvarchar(5)), '')
FROM 
    FilteredOpportunity O 
INNER JOIN 
    Filtereddtm_unit H ON O.pcrm_homeid = H.dtm_unitid
WHERE
    O.dtm_project = @ProjectId AND 
    NOT O.pcrm_rdeid IS NULL AND
    O.statuscode = 265780001
```

How can I sort this list?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `sort the list`?

Comment: So, Realtor Firm Deals return a data like this: G2-18, G3-21, G2-13, G-15, G1-16, G2-17, G3-9, G1-11, G2-12, B2-22, B-23, B-24, B1-25, B-28, B-29, B-30, B2-31, F2-69, F-70, F-71, F-72. I want to be able to sort it alphabetically.

Comment: So @RelatorFirmDeals is a table variable? what is your table variable structure?

Comment: DECLARE @RelatorFirmDeals VARCHAR(8000)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that could work for you.

First, grab the `udf_Split` user-defined function (UDF) from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943509/twp-multi-select-parameters-in-ssrs-not-displaying-results-for-when-selected-mor) question's answer. With this UDF you to pass the delimited string as a parameter, and it will return a table with a row for each value.

Once you have that in place, then all you need to do is use that UDF in the following manner.

```
DECLARE @RelatorFirmDeals VARCHAR(8000) = 'G2-18, G3-21, G2-13, G-15, G1-16, G2-17, G3-9, G1-11, G2-12, B2-22, B-23, B-24, B1-25, B-28, B-29, B-30, B2-31, F2-69, F-70, F-71, F-72'

SELECT LTRIM(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(Value))
    FROM dbo.udf_Split(@RelatorFirmDeals, ',')
    ORDER BY 1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, ''));
```

This will be the resulting string:

`B-23, B-24, B-28, B-29, B-30, B1-25, B2-22, B2-31, F-70, F-71, F-72, F2-69, G-15, G1-11, G1-16, G2-12, G2-13, G2-17, G2-18, G3-21, G3-9`

Hope this helps out.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically breaking down the string and placing it into a table variable, ordering the table, then putting it back into a string. One thing to note is that, since this is sorted as a string and not as integers, G-9 will go after G-10. If you want to sort this alphabetically and then numerically you will need to break down the strings into 2 columns, 1 for letters and 1 for numbers then sort accordingly.

If you have SQL Server 2016 then this could be simplified with the [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @input_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'G2-18, G3-21, G2-13, G-15, G1-16, G2-17, G3-9, G1-11, G2-12, B2-22, B-23, B-24, B1-25, B-28, B-29, B-30, B2-31, F2-69, F-70, F-71, F-72'
DECLARE @delimiter NVARCHAR(MAX) = ', '

DECLARE @output_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @values_table TABLE (
string_values NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

WHILE (SELECT LEN(@input_string) - LEN(REPLACE(@input_string,@delimiter,''))) > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT @values_table
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@input_string,0,CHARINDEX(', ',@input_string))

    SET @input_string = SUBSTRING(@input_string,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)+2,LEN(@input_string))
END

INSERT @values_table
SELECT @input_string

DECLARE @row_counter INT = 1

WHILE @row_counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @values_table)
BEGIN
    SET @output_string = @output_string + (
        SELECT
            string_values
        FROM (
            SELECT
                string_values
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY string_values) AS row_num
            FROM @values_table) sub_query
        WHERE row_num = @row_counter) + @delimiter
    SET @row_counter = @row_counter + 1
END

SELECT SUBSTRING(@output_string,0,LEN(@output_string)-2)
```

Here is the TSQL for a UDF that takes an input string to be sorted and a delimiter to split it on.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_order_string(@input_string NVARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS   

BEGIN

    DECLARE @output_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    DECLARE @values_table TABLE (
    string_values NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    WHILE (SELECT LEN(@input_string) - LEN(REPLACE(@input_string,@delimiter,''))) > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT @values_table
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@input_string,0,CHARINDEX(', ',@input_string))

        SET @input_string = SUBSTRING(@input_string,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)+2,LEN(@input_string))
    END

    INSERT @values_table
    SELECT @input_string

    DECLARE @row_counter INT = 1

    WHILE @row_counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @values_table)
    BEGIN
        SET @output_string = @output_string + (
            SELECT
                string_values
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    string_values
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY string_values) AS row_num
                FROM @values_table) sub_query
            WHERE row_num = @row_counter) + @delimiter
        SET @row_counter = @row_counter + 1
    END

    SET @output_string = SUBSTRING(@output_string,0,LEN(@output_string)-2)

    RETURN @output_string

END
```