# Pad user input with zeros in a multiple value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to pad numbers in a multiple value parameter to make them have 8 characters in length? Right now I am using:

=Right("00000000" & Parameters!Accounts.Value,8)

in an invisible parameter then that parameter is passed to the in part of my query. When I have, multiple values unchecked it works properly, but as soon as I turn on multiple values I get an error

> The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘ActualAccounts’ contains an error: Operator ‘&’ is not defined for string “00000000” and type ‘Object()’.”

I want the user to be able to paste in a list of accounts like:

```
93874
93932128
3838
```

And then it queries the database as

```
00093874
93932128
00003838
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that could work for you.

First, grab the `udf_Split` user-defined function (UDF) from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943509/twp-multi-select-parameters-in-ssrs-not-displaying-results-for-when-selected-mor) question's answer. With this UDF you to pass the delimited string as a parameter, and it will return a table with a row for each value. This is how SSRS sends the data to SQL Server when it comes to multi value parameters.

Once you have that in place, then all you need to do is use that UDF in the following manner.

```
DECLARE @ActualAccounts varchar(100) = '93874,93932128,3838'

SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)), 8) AS Accounts
    FROM dbo.udf_Split(@ActualAccounts, ',');
```

Results:

```
Accounts
--------
00093874
93932128
00003838
```

Then you could use this in the SQL for the report

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountNumber IN (SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)), 8)
        FROM dbo.udf_Split(@ActualAccounts, ','));
```

This answer assumes the name of the SSRS parameter is ActualAccounts. You should be able to fit this into a stored procedure, if that is what you are using. <s>It should work in straight SQL if you have that embedded in the RDL, too</s>.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So far this seems to be what I am looking for except when a user types into the multiple parameter I am returned with udf.Split has too many arguments.

So as an example I type in 93874 hit enter then 93932128 then enter. The parameter then adds it to 93874, 9392128 and it get that error.

Comment: So, you are trying to use this in SQL that is embedded in the RDL, am I right? No stored procedure? If so, would you be able to move the code to a SP? :) I am starting to think that may be your best bet.

Comment: That is correct my main SQL query is embedded into the report. I did create the function in one our databases though. We prefer to have it within the report if possible.

Comment: Got it. I was mistaken in telling you that this will work with embedded SQL, sorry about that. Unfortunately, it will only work with a stored procedure. Willing to be flexible on this one, and use an SP? I can't think of another solution right off hand.

Comment: Yeah that's why originally I was trying to pass the parameter (Accounts) that the user enters in to another invisible  parameter (ActualAccounts) and use an expression to pad the zeros. But I wasn't sure if I could do it through code in the report. 

As for the stored procedure would that then work with the multiple values if the user copy and pasted accounts from a separate row in excel into the report? 
    account1
    account2
    account3
    etc..

Comment: That should work with copy and pasting values, as long as they are in one column if data in the dropdown. I have done that before, and I *love* the fact that it can be done. Sometimes, picking values from a huge list can be a hassle; being able to paste in values is nice.